# Create System Restore Point in Windows 10

Tags: windows, system-restore

I want to use Window API to create System Restore Point (SRP). However, creating SRP is limited in 24 hours.

Here're my steps

- Add SystemRestorePointCreationFrequency under the registry key HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SystemRestore and set to Zero.

In source code

- Call LoadLibraryW(L"srclient.dll")
- Get GetProcAddress of SRSetRestorePointW
- Call SRSetRestorePointW method.

this method only create SRP in the first calling. In the second calling, it always return previous sequenceNumber(STATEMGRSTATUS.llSequenceNumber).
it seem that SRSetRestorePointW does not refer SystemRestorePointCreationFrequency.

I tried using powershell to create 2 SRPs, it works well (without reboot system )

```
Checkpoint-Computer -Description 'Install_TEST' -RestorePointType 'APPLICATION_INSTALL'
```

This source code is referred from MSD. But it has this issue. (learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sr/using-system-restore)

Answer (score 1):

You must be using Windows 8 or later for getting `SystemRestorePointCreationFrequency` to work.

1. On first call set `eventtype` to `BEGIN_SYSTEM_CHANGE`.
2. On second call set `eventtype` to `END_SYSTEM_CHANGE` and set
   `SequenceNumber` returned from the first call.